# Correct Way to Encode HTML Page Title

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application. I'm setting the page's title based on content from my database.

Because this content is entered by the user, it can contain any characters, including ones that could be interpreted as HTML markup. Therefore, I am HTML-encoding this content before setting the title.

But I see this is causing problems by producing overly encoded results:

```
<title>Hoigaard&amp;#39;s Nordic Walking Tuesdays</title>
```

What is the correct way to safely encode text used to set the title tag?

Comment: Did you first validate that it is necessary to encode the value before setting `Page.Title`?

Comment: Well, in the extreme case where the text was `</title></head><body>...`, I could see real problems develop. I do not consider it good form to not encode this content.

Comment: No. I meant did you validate that `Page.Title` does not *already* encode the result?

Comment: D'oh! Looking at the problem text, I can in fact see it *is* encoded twice. Looks like that's the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this, and it appears setting `Page.Title` *already* performs the encoding.  So your additional encoding is resulting in double-encoded results.  Just set the `Page.Title` directly:

```
Page.Title = "Test & Testing";
```

result:

```
<title>Test &amp; Testing</title>
```

Comment: what's the case for javascript ??

Answer (score 0):

Use some function similar to the PHP function `htmlspecialchars()`:

```
<%
' Copyright (c) 2009, reusablecode.blogspot.com; some rights reserved.
' This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution License.

' Convert special characters to HTML entities.
function htmlspecialchars(someString)
    ' Critical that ampersand is converted first, since all entities contain them.
    htmlspecialchars = replace(replace(replace(replace(someString, "&", "&amp;"), ">", "&gt;"), "<", "&lt;"), """", "&quot;")
end function
%>
```

source: http://snipplr.com/view/12207/htmlspecialchars/

Comment: Looks like the problem is that ASP.NET already encodes the title, so I'm encoding it twice.